# Class 'org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl' could not be found. Please verify it is on the classpath

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, xerces

I'm using WildFly and Jboss for API deployment.
Below code throwing exception when I'm hitting one of the API.

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory", "org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl");
// Here the exception is occurring
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance("org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl", ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
dbFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
dbFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "");
```

Exception:

```
ERROR [stderr] JAXP: find factoryId =javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
ERROR [stderr] JAXP: find factoryId =javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
ERROR [stderr] JAXP: found system property, value=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
ERROR [stderr] JAXP: created new instance of class org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl using ClassLoader: null
ERROR [stderr] JAXP: find factoryId =javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
ERROR [stderr] JAXP: find factoryId =javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
ERROR [stderr] JAXP: find factoryId =javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory
ERROR [stderr] JAXP: find factoryId =javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
ERROR [stderr] JAXP: found system property, value=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
ERROR [stderr] JAXP: created new instance of class org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl using ClassLoader: null
ERROR [stderr] JAXP: find factoryId =javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
ERROR [stderr] JAXP: find factoryId =javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory
ERROR [stderr] JAXP: find factoryId =javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory
ERROR [stderr] JAXP: find factoryId =javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
ERROR [stderr] JAXP: found system property, value=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
ERROR [stderr] JAXP: created new instance of class org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl using ClassLoader: null
ERROR [stderr] JAXP: find factoryId =javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
ERROR [stderr] JAXP: Looking up system property 'javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom'
ERROR [stderr] JAXP: The property is undefined.
ERROR [stderr] JAXP: found null in $java.home/conf/jaxp.properties
ERROR [stderr] JAXP: factory 'org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl' was found for http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom
ERROR [stderr] JAXP: find factoryId =javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
ERROR [stderr] JAXP: found system property, value=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
ERROR [stderr] JAXP: created new instance of class org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl using ClassLoader: null
ERROR [stderr] (Exception Multicaster Thread15) com.blazesoft.server.base.NdServiceSessionException: Service session Id number 1.
ERROR [stderr] (Exception Multicaster Thread15) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
                SEVERE [com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler] (default task-1) com.blazesoft.server.base.NdServiceSessionException: Service session Id number 1.
                Class 'org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl' could not be found. Please verify it is on the classpath. while evaluating "XYZ" in function ABC
                        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
                        ...
```

I have added a jars file in build.xml of ant build. So in my jar, I have below jars in the \WEB-INF\lib.

```
<fileset id="required-jars" dir="${product.lib}">
    <include name="xerces.jar"/>
    <include name="resolver.jar"/>
    <include name="serializer.jar"/>
    <include name="xalan.jar"/>
    <include name="xercesImpl.jar"/>
    <include name="xml-apis.jar"/>
</fileset>
```

Xerces version is 2.6.1 
JBoss Module version 1.9.1 
WildFly version 17.0.1

Comment: It is for tomcat.

Comment: You're correct and you have `xercesImpl.jar` already.  Retracted.

Comment: What version of WildFly are you using?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Xerces version is 2.6.1
Jboos Module version 1.9.1
WildFly version 17.0.1